# How did you learn BackboneJS?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm having a difficult time understanding its tutorials.
Either they are too advanced or do not work
If you are an advanced user, please tell me how you started off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derick Bailey has a blog post on this, although it's a bit old: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/13/resources-for-and-how-i-learned-backbone-js/

They way I started (although with Marionette which is built on top of Backbone) was to create some small projects to see how the various parts worked together: http://davidsulc.com/blog/category/backbone-js/backbone-marionette/

To help other people along, I then wrote [a book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) that builds a non-trivial application step by step: http://davidsulc.github.io/marionette-gentle-introduction/#contacts

If you learn best by digging in source code, you can see it here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction

Comment: thank you david, its very helpful